# SCSS encapsulation in Angular library

Tags: angular, sass

I want to create an Angular library that is "themeable", meaning clients of the library can apply e.g. their own color. I've checked how material design is doing it, and what they are doing is something like this:

In (library)/theming.scss:

```
@mixin hello-button($theme) {
  $hello-background: map-get($theme, 'hello-background');
  .hello {
    background: $hello-background;
  }
}
@mixin apply-theme($theme) {
  @include hello-button($theme);
}
```

In (client)/styles.scss:

```
@import '~library/theming';
$theme: (
  'hello-background': yellow
);
@include apply-theme($theme);
```

But this sets global classes... Here the ".hello" class is global, so anything that will have a ".hello" class is going to be yellow, even if it's just the same name by accident.

So my question is, isn't there a way to customize scss without global classes, which would be more in the spirit of view encapsulation of Angular? I know that I could style it using ngStyle, but I'd prefer a scss way.

Comment: Material design classes are prefixed with `mat` if I'm not mistaken, probably to avoid the same problem. So you could just make sure that you have a prefix for your classes

Comment: yeah but what if my prefix is "bla" and someone else also makes a library with the prefix "bla". Age old problem with prefixes, that's why we have the view encapsulation concept now.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, please check https://angular.io/guide/component-styles, `:host` seciton.

Comment: so what exactly are you suggesting, overriding some defaults with ::ng-deep (which is going to be deprecated)?

Comment: :host limit the scope of css to only the component you are working on. Actually without `:host` you can still apply that stylesheet after this component is loaded, so this might populate your global. However if this component is not loaded, you are still fine. The idea is to write your css along with the component

Comment: but then how can you theme the library?

Comment: You want to load styles later, not want to pollute global, not want to use prefix, not want to put the styles with the component. You are asking if you can put a stylesheet in global space while applying it to your components automatically without any marker.